# Need to make a pop up dialog box in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, mobile-development

I'm new to Flutter and learning it continuously.

I'm currently imitating a counter app for learning and I'm almost done with it, but there is something I tried to do it through many solutions I found on other posts here but they all did not work.

I'm trying to make a pop up dialog box that pops up after tapping on the yellow circle in the follwoing screenshot:

[image: tap on the circle]

And the dialog box should be similar to this:

[image: select circle color]

Hope someone can help in this.

Here is the code that I'm working on it:

```
import 'package:floating_counter/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';

import 'main.dart';

void main() => runApp(NewCounter());

class NewCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewCounterState createState() => _NewCounterState();
}

class _NewCounterState extends State<NewCounter> {
  final FocusNode textNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode numberNode = FocusNode();

  TextStyle labelStyle;
  TextStyle numberStyle;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textNode.addListener(onFocusChange);
  }

  void onFocusChange() {
    setState(() {
      labelStyle = textNode.hasFocus ? TextStyle(color: kMainColor) : null;
    });
    setState(() {
      numberStyle = numberNode.hasFocus ? TextStyle(color: kMainColor) : null;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textNode.removeListener(onFocusChange);
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: kMainColor,
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.close,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    PageTransition(
                      type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      child: CountNumbering(),
                    ),
                  );
                });
              }),
          title: Text(
            'New Counter',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/floppy-disk.png',
                  width: 20.0,
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                }),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 15.0, top: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 0.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      focusNode: textNode,
                      cursorColor: kMainColor,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
                        labelText: 'Name',
                        labelStyle: labelStyle,
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xFF5A5A5A),
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: kMainColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 15.0, top: 0.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      focusNode: numberNode,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      cursorColor: kMainColor,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
                        labelText: 'Start value',
                        labelStyle: numberStyle,
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xFF5A5A5A),
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: kMainColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 33.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Select a Color',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          spreadRadius: 2,
                          blurRadius: 2,
                          // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      color: kMainColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show the dialog like this by using `GridView`:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Dialog(
    child: Container(
      width: (5 * 50) + (4 * 10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: colorsList.length,
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                  crossAxisCount: 5),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var color = colorsList[index];
            return MaterialButton(
              elevation: 0,
              color: color,
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                setState(() {
                  selectedColor = color;
                });
              },
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
              ),
            );
          }),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image]

Few changes:

- Don't call setState and Navigator together.

```dart
setState(() {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    PageTransition(
                      type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      child: CountNumbering(),
                    ),
                  );
                });
```

- dispose FocusNode

```dart
// inside dispose method
textNode.dispose();
numberNode.dispose();
```

Full code:

```dart
class NewCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewCounterState createState() => _NewCounterState();
}

class _NewCounterState extends State<NewCounter> {
  final FocusNode textNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode numberNode = FocusNode();
  Color selectedColor = Colors.black;
  final int colorsInaRow = 5;
  final double colorBoxSize = 50.0;

  TextStyle labelStyle;
  TextStyle numberStyle;
  List<Color> colorsList = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.pink,
    Colors.purple,
    Colors.indigo,
    Colors.blueGrey,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.lightBlue,
    Colors.cyan,
    Colors.teal,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.lightGreen,
    Colors.yellow,
    Colors.amber,
    Colors.orange,
    Colors.deepOrange,
    Colors.brown,
    Colors.grey,
    Colors.black,
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textNode.addListener(onFocusChange);
  }

  void onFocusChange() {
    setState(() {
      labelStyle = textNode.hasFocus ? TextStyle(color: Colors.black) : null;
    });
    setState(() {
      numberStyle = numberNode.hasFocus ? TextStyle(color: Colors.black) : null;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textNode.removeListener(onFocusChange);
    textNode.dispose();
    numberNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.close,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigator.push(
                //   context,
                //   PageTransition(
                //     type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                //     duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                //     child: CountNumbering(),
                //   ),
                // );
              }),
          title: Text(
            'New Counter',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.folder_open),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 15.0, top: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 0.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      focusNode: textNode,
                      cursorColor: Colors.black,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
                        labelText: 'Name',
                        labelStyle: labelStyle,
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xFF5A5A5A),
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 15.0, top: 0.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      focusNode: numberNode,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                      cursorColor: Colors.black,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
                        labelText: 'Start value',
                        labelStyle: numberStyle,
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xFF5A5A5A),
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 33.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Select a Color',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          spreadRadius: 2,
                          blurRadius: 2,
                          // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) => Dialog(
                            child: Container(
                              width: (colorsInaRow * colorBoxSize) +
                                  ((colorsInaRow - 1) * 10), // mainAxisSpacing
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: GridView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: colorsList.length,
                                  gridDelegate:
                                      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                                          crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                                          mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                                          crossAxisCount: colorsInaRow),
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    var color = colorsList[index];
                                    return MaterialButton(
                                      elevation: 0,
                                      color: color,
                                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                        setState(() {
                                          selectedColor = color;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                        height: colorBoxSize,
                                        width: colorBoxSize,
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      color: selectedColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I copied the full code that you posted, when I hit "run" no dialog box popped up and the following lines appeared in the console: https://justpaste.it/8m9bl

Comment: i'm awaiting your reply please.